# C# Поиск объекта по шаблону и выполнения метода OpenCV 'EmguCV'

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

читал инфу на сайтах про OpenCV но к сожалению данная библиотека не подходит под язык C#, Пробовал найти хотя-бы пример по EmguCV но к сожалению ни где не нашёл, прошу у вас помощи.
То есть задача заключается в следующем:

1. Есть картинка (Модель) поплавка из игры Minecraft
2. И есть функция по которой мы будет получать скрин с окна Игры Minecraft.
3. Необходимо по скрину найти совпадение по данной картинке (Поплавок) и сверить если его текстура или цвет совпадает то, это ещё рыба не клюнула, а при поклёвке поплавок утаскивает под воду и он становится тёмно-серым, соответственно программа должна отследить данное событие и вывести сообщение "Рыба Клюнула".
4. Ребят пример кода могу скинуть только на Pyton но там написано на OpenCV Который не реализован на целевом языке.
   Пожалуйста кто может подскажите как сделать или скиньте пример, а если будет возможность и решение подкинуть я против не буду)))
   Картинки с низу:[image: Поплавок находится в ожидании поклёвки] Поплавок находится в ожидании поклёвки и примерный вид поплавка когда он будет под водой (Цвет может меняться, поэтому нужна проверка на изменение в процентном соотношении или проверка на RGB):[image: Поплавок ушёл под воду когда рыба клюнула] Ну и конечно же сама картинка (Скрин рыбалки)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть же готовые боты для рыбалки в майнкрафте на джаве.

Comment: Я понимаю что они есть, мне необходимо во всём деле разобраться, я ведь дал игру к примеру, я не говорю что именно мне нужно для данной игры )

Comment: Смысл не для того чтобы найти и пользоваться ботом, а для того чтобы научиться выполнять данные функции и развивать свой мозг и делать вещи )))

Comment: Тогда по сути вам нужно научиться тренировать модели нейронок по фоткам, только и всего.

Comment: Да но я не могу найти подходящую статью или пример поэтому обратился сюда

Comment: aepot Подскажите или покажите пожалуйста примерный код.